# How to show web site subtitle

Tags: asp.net, web

When I type "stack overflow" on google it shows

**Stack Overflow**
* Newest Questions          *Android
* Careers 2.0               *C++
* Java                      *Featured

how can I add this type of SUBTITLE [I don't know whether its name is subtitle or not] to my web site (asp.net)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google site links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600847/google-site-links)

Comment: Have a look at [Google Webmaster Tools-Site Links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)

Comment: Those are Sitelinks, see duplicate. See also [Sitelinks - Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?topic=8523): _"We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them"_.